# What town hall level should I be in Gold 3 in Clash of Clans

Tags: clash-of-clans

I am currently a Town Hall 5 in Gold 3 with 1411 trophies but a lot of my opponents have either TH 8 or TH 9. Am I at too high of a trophy range?

Comment: I believe it would be best for you to see for yourself. If you are getting attacked and losing your resources a lot, and frequently, I would advise you to go down. The good thing with going high up the leagues at a small town hall is that higher level town halls will have huge loot penalties. Town Hall 6 get 90% of lootable resources, TH7 get 50%, TH8 get 25% and TH9+ get 5%. I don't find that many TH6 in Gold3, farmers rarely go after small loots, and you usually get huge loot in comparison on the abandoned TH7 and up.

Comment: Instead of opinion-based, this question is actually too broad. For a particular TH level and specific criteria, there's certainly an optimal trophy range for a base to sit at. Unfortunately, this question is asked in reverse and none of those details were provided.

Answer (score 7):

For farming gold and elixir, it's probably better for you to be in Silver 1 or Silver 2, around the 1200-1300 range. This is because:

1. you find more abandoned bases there, where you can steal loot from full collectors and mines without having to break into their bases for storages, and
2. You can find easier bases in TH4-TH6 in that trophy range than in Gold 3.

I would recommend you stay in that range until you start needing dark elixir in TH7/TH8, only then go back to Gold 3.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend TH8 in GOLD 3, with TH5, everyone can WRECK you, and I recommend Silver 2 or 3, or even Bronze 1.